# TSQL -- display results of two queries on one row in SSMS

Tags: t-sql, ssms, resultset, display, recordset

I am using TSQL, SSMS v.17.9.1 The underlying db is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP3

For display purposes, I want to concatenate the results of two queries:

```
SELECT TOP 1 colA as 'myCol1' FROM tableA
--
SELECT TOP 1 colB  as 'myCol2' FROM tableB
```

and display the results from the queries in one row in SSMS.
(The TOP 1 directive would hopefully guarantee the same number of results from each query, which would assist displaying them together. If this could be generalized to TOP 10 *per query* that would help also)

Comment: Have you searched for `[tsql] concatenate`? Using subqueries, rather than `union`, lets you get the results in a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any number of rows, it assumes you want to pair ordered by the values in the column displayed

```
        With 
        TableA_CTE AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 colA as myCol1
        ,Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ColA DESC)  AS RowOrder 
        FROM tableA
        ),
        TableB_CTE AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 colB as myCol2
        ,Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ColB DESC)  AS RowOrder 
        FROM tableB
        )
        SELECT A.myCol1, B.MyCol2
        FROM TableA_CTE AS A
        INNER JOIN TableB_CTE AS B
           ON A.RowOrder = B.RowOrder
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the issues, I've corrected but keep your answer in you deserve a vote too.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two issues with the accepted answer:
I)  a missing comma before the line: "Table B As"
II) TSQL seems to find it recursive as written, so I re-wrote it in a non-recursive way:

This is a re-working of the accepted answer that actually works in T-SQL:

```
USE [Database_1];

 With 
   CTE_A AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 [Col1] as myCol1 
    ,Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [Col2] desc)  AS RowOrder 
    FROM [TableA]
    )
    ,
    CTE_B AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 [Col2] as myCol2
    ,Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [Col2] desc)  AS RowOrder 
    FROM  [TableB] 
    )
    SELECT A.myCol1, B.myCol2
    FROM CTE_A AS A
    INNER JOIN CTE_B  AS B
       ON ( A.RowOrder = B.RowOrder)
```